# Environment specific configurations in Felix Configurator

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Felix Configurator allows to apply service configurations using JSON files. I provided a bunch of json files under OSGI-INF/configurations and those were picked by the configurator bundle which applied the configs correctly. This is great but I am thinking of applying the configurations on environment basis like Sling run mode configs or Spring profiles for that matter.

I have looked into the Felix Configurator code and specs but could not find any reference to such a capability.

OSGi experts, please suggest how this could be achieved.

Comment: What do you want to change between environments? Just things like urls and passwords or also structural changes?

Comment: yes, urls and passwords etc. No structural changes. Will Felix Interpolation help here? Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: Yes .. felix interpolation works very well with configurator.

Comment: ok that will help but would add one more task from deployment perspective, the development team must provide the interpolation config file to the deployment team.

Comment: I like the code (including docker images) to be independent of the stage. The config can then reside in the stage. For example in k8s you can use secrets or config maps for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to replace values in a config but have no structural changes then [felix interpolation](https://github.com/apache/felix-dev/tree/master/configadmin-plugins/interpolation) is the best solution.

A good practice for docker is to use environment variables:

```html
com.my.userinfo:
"greeting": "Hello $[env:USER]!"
```

Just make sure you use the newest version of felix configadmin as interpolation uses a new configadmin feature from OSGi R7.

Comment: This would help but I am thinking of an inherent feature of Configurator where we provide a system property like Sling run mode or Spring profile and create a config such as service.dev.json or service.prod.json and then Configurator will only read the appropriate file based upon the mode. This will get deployed along with the code and managed with code too, with interpolation, development team would have to provide the interpolation config for each env and the config file will have to be provided every time there is a change. Anyway, just a thought, I am marking this as accepted answer.

Comment: Profiles or run modes would be a nice enhancement. I have seen very bad instances of them though. One customer provided configs for all stages including passwords and deployed them to an open maven repo.. Not a good idea. 
You can look into the sling feature model. Combining features (each including config) can do what you want.